# Am I allowed to carry caffeine pills on US domestic flight?

Tags: air-travel, tsa, drugs, prohibited-items

I bought those pills on Amazon and they're in the original bottle. (The seal is opened)

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

Caffeine is a legal medication in the US, and caffeine pills are sold over-the-counter in every drugstore and supermarket with no prescription required (up to 200 mg per pill, I believe).

Pills generally are allowed in either checked or carry-on luggage.  See https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all and search for "pills" or "medication".  They don't fall into any prohibited category like sharp objects, explosives, or liquids.